# translating LVDS to LVTTL using amplifier and high speed output buffer

Tags: operational-amplifier, clock, buffer, high-speed, lvds

I am receiving an LVDS clock differential signals and need to convert them to LVTTL .
the problem is that the LVDS frequency is above 500Mhz and the LVTTL output needs to drive a 50ohm resistors, when the LVTTL VOH=2.4Vmin , then the current drive capabilities should be bigger than 48mA.
finding a chip to do the conversion with those limitations is very hard.
I tried to solve this problem as the circuit below.
it is a very basic circuit just to see it the idea works , first the LVDS clock is connected to a diff amplifier  , lets assume also the output of this amplifier is differential and i take only one output .
this signal is going to a circuit (needs to design ) that can translate the output of the amplifier to be able to connect it to the (push/pull) output buffer .
since the output buffer is connected as an emitter follower which is actually a current amplifier maybe i can reach the current drive capabilities .
can you look at my circuit and give me feedbacks ?
[image]

***** question added : any BJT recommended that can work at 500Mhz?**
is this topology of push/pull can work ?

Comment: To start off, the '3906/'3904 transistors you've shown aren't anywhere near fast enough for your application, 500 MHz.

Comment: For the diff receiver, there are LVDS receivers that are advertised to work at 500 MHz, something like the MAX911.

Comment: @SteveSh , please ignore the part number of the bipolar transistors , i just added them to show the ides

Comment: Didn't you already ask the same or similar question? Why start another, and you never accepted any answer either, were they not good? Also, why a discrete buffer, why not a buffer chip that can drive the load at the required frequency?

Comment: @Justme , here i started a new thread since i am suggesting a solution. all the solutions didn't really work , i took all of the suggestions but didnt find something that can work with my limitations

Comment: @Danny Am - Then sure, what you showed will work, conceptually.  The devil is in the details.  Like someone said in response to your earlier question, 500 MHz and ~50 mA is more like a RF design.

Comment: anyone knows a BJT that can work with 500Mhz?
do you think the push/pull configuration is ok? is there other configuration to use?

Comment: This sounds like an RF preamp/power amp application. Have you considered an MMIC or RF amp or power transistor?

Comment: @TimWilliams can you explain more about MMIC or RF amp ? i dont have much knowledge on RF design

Comment: To break down the problem, as I understand it so far: you have a signal source of some amplitude and bandwidth (if it's a high frequency clock and nothing else, the bandwidth will be small). You need a different amplitude but the same basic signal. You need a linear amplifier. Thus, simply use a balun (differential input, single-ended output) to couple LVDS into the amplifier, and size the amplifier for LVTTL scale output. It will match well into 50 ohms. Done.

Comment: If you need some range of frequency (adjustable clock?) or pulse width or whatever, those adjustments may be feasible (AC coupling might be dealt with using a DC restorer network for example), or if say a gated clock, maybe a separate gating/keying circuit can be used; the on/off times may not be very clean (takes some time for DC bias or output amplitude to stabilize?) but that may or may not be important for the application. All the more reason why knowing the application is important.

Comment: @Danny Am - "i don't have much knowledge on RF design".  But at 500 MHz, you're in the RF realm.  Every interconnect is a transmission line.  Parasitics can kill you (metaphorically).  At 500 MHz and above, most clocks look like sine waves.  What is your background?

Comment: @TimWilliams…I understand your suggestion with the Balun to use as a transformer…I got actually another limitation on the application..that the lvds clock Duty cycle I receive is not constant…sometimes it can be 50% and sometimes for example can have a high for 1ns and low for 20ns …it means it is random …and here the Balun may be a problematic to use since when it is low for example for about 20ns it acts like a DC and the transformer can’t pass this energy …so here because i can receive pulses randomly this might not be good ..

Comment: @SteveSh I am an electrical engineer and board designer … but haven’t worked much with RF design

Comment: That might not matter; there are ways to deal with DC balance, such as a DC restore network, or adjusting the code slightly to reduce long-term imbalance.  As example, Ethernet uses pulses at ~100MHz yet is transformer coupled; for all we know, your application might be similar but scaled to a somewhat higher frequency.  You've said almost nothing about your application so it's impossible for us to eliminate such methods as a possibility.

Comment: Indeed calling it a "clock" seems to imply something more stable and consistent than it apparently is; but without any information about how it may vary, and how fast, we can only guess at solutions.